# Swift Code says "expected declaration" at if (Donestate == true)

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode and swift. I'm getting the message Expected Declaration. Can you please help me figure out what's wrong?

CODE:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let grayColor = UIColor.gray
    var Done1State:Bool = false
    @IBOutlet weak var Name1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name6: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Time1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Time2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Time3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Time4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Time5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Time6: UILabel!
    @IBAction func Done1(_ sender: Any) {
        Done1State = true
    }
    if ( Done1State == true ) {
        Name1.backgroundColor = grayColor
        Time1.backgroundColor = grayColor
    }
    @IBAction func AddNewTask(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var AddNewTask: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AddNewTask.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        AddNewTask.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue"{
            Done1State = true
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `if ( Done1State == true ) {` is outside a execution context (ie a method)

Comment: Move your if-block into a function.